# Usage and meaning of とのことです

Tags: politeness, keigo, business-japanese

I see this often in business emails, I guess it is not very important in terms of meaning but I couldn't find any post on stackexchange about it.

What does とのことです add to a sentence? Here is the latest example I've read:

> 碑文谷警察署の本町二丁目交番とのことです

Comment: = 『碑文谷警察署の本町二丁目交番』とのことです。

Comment: 「～～とのことです」は「～～だそうです」のformalな言い方だと思います・・・

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> とのことです

is a hearsay and a bit formal way.

For example, your boss said Mike is working at 碑文谷警察署の本町二丁目交番.

Then, your business partner asked you where Mike is working at?

So you answered

> 碑文谷警察署の本町二丁目交番とのことです。

If you like to express it in common way, you can say

> Mikeは碑文谷警察署の本町二丁目交番で働いています。